# How to refactor this Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

Consider this helper method:

```
module SomeHelper

  def display_button
    Foo.find_by_id params[:id] and Foo.find(params[:id]).organizer.name != current_name and Foo.find(params[:id]).friends.find_by_name current_name
  end

end
```

How to refactor into something more readable?

Rails 3.2.2

Comment: is this supposed to be boolean?

Comment: Yes, it is boolean. I should have added that to the question.

Comment: Please note that [`and`/`or` is *not* the same as `&&`/`||` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - Actually, that was causing a problem. I want the `and/&&` to be evaluated last. `and` is lower precedence. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can factorize the call to `Foo.find(params[:id])` and use `exists?` for the third condition

```
module SomeHelper
  def display_button
    foo = foo.find_by_id params[:id]
    foo and foo.organizer.name != current_name and foo.friends.where(:name => current_name).exists?
  end
end
```

You can also create several methods to gain on reusability (and will save trouble if you model changes):

```
module SomeHelper
  def display_button
    foo = foo.find_by_id params[:id]
    foo && !is_organizer?(foo, current_name) && has_friend?(foo, current_name)
  end

  def is_organizer?(foo, name)
    foo.organizer.name == name
  end 

  def has_friend?(foo, name)
    foo.friends.where(:name => name).exists?
  end
end
```

Comment: Breaking into multiple methods is really the key to refactoring the original method, which was doing too much.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
module SomeHelper

  def display_button?
    if foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
      foo.organizer.name != current_name if foo.friends.find_by_name(current_name)
    end
  end

end
```

**Note:** if the helper method is returning a boolean, I would append the name with a `?` ... ruby convention.

Answer (score 1):

try invokes the passed block on non-nil objects. Returns nil otherwise.  So the return will be nil,true,false depending on your data.

```
def display_button
    Foo.find_by_id(params[:id]).try do |foo|
       foo.organizer.name != current_name && 
         foo.friends.find_by_name current_name
    end
  end
```